# unique key violation occuring on a unique value combination

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, constraint

SQL SERVER 2008
I have a mapping table that contains a deleted date column.  Since the table uses a surrogate key as its unique identifier there is a uniqueness constraint on the table.  This constraint contains each of the foreign key values and the deleted date.

I have a process that runs each night and attmepts to modify this data based on an external data source.  The process is attempting to update a record and set its deleted date to GETDATE().  There is currently a record in the mapping table witht he same foreign key values and a deleted date of 2011-12-17 00:17:22.157.  The process is returning the following error

Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UNQ_tsitemapping_fullcolumnlist'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tSiteMapping'. The duplicate key value is (4, , 5, , 1394, 154, Dec 21 2011  6:59AM).

Shouldnt the inclusion of the deleted date in the uniqueness constraint mean that this is a unique value?  Why would I be getting a UNIQUE KEY constraint violation on this table?
Any suggestions on how to fix this problem would be welcome.

As Per GBN's comment below.  Here is the table definition.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tSiteMapping](
    [intSiteMappingID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [intEntityID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [intParentCompanyID] [int] NULL,
    [intMarketSegmentID] [int] NULL,
    [intRegionID] [int] NULL,
    [intSiteID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dtEntered] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [dtModified] [datetime] NULL,
    [dtDeleted] [datetime] NULL,
    [intdivisionid] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_lSiteMapping] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [intSiteMappingID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UNQ_tsitemapping_fullcolumnlist] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [intEntityID] ASC,
    [intParentCompanyID] ASC,
    [intMarketSegmentID] ASC,
    [intRegionID] ASC,
    [intSiteID] ASC,
    [intdivisionid] ASC,
    [dtDeleted] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tSiteMapping]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tSiteMapping_lEntity] FOREIGN KEY([intEntityID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[lEntity] ([intEntityID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tSiteMapping] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tSiteMapping_lEntity]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tSiteMapping]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tSiteMapping_tSite] FOREIGN KEY([intSiteID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tSite] ([intSiteID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tSiteMapping] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tSiteMapping_tSite]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tSiteMapping] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_lSiteMapping_dtEntered]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [dtEntered]
GO
```

The following query is the query that is failing

```
UPDATE tSiteMapping
   SET dtDeleted = GETDATE()
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM crm...qapps a
                          JOIN crm...parent_company pc ON pc.id = a.intparentcompanyid
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN tSite s ON s.intAppID = a.appid AND s.dtDeleted IS NULL
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN lEntity e ON e.strEntity = a.enterprise_name AND e.dtDeleted IS NULL
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN lParentCompany lpc ON lpc.strParentCompany = CASE 
                                                                                           WHEN SUBSTRING(pc.companyname, 0, CHARINDEX(' - ', pc.companyname, 0)) LIKE '%Canada%' THEN
                                                                                                REPLACE(SUBSTRING(pc.companyname, 0, CHARINDEX(' - ', pc.companyname, 0)), 'Canada', 'CAN')
                                                                                           WHEN SUBSTRING(pc.companyname, 0, CHARINDEX(' - ', pc.companyname, 0)) LIKE '%  USA%' THEN
                                                                                                REPLACE(SUBSTRING(pc.companyname, 0, CHARINDEX(' - ', pc.companyname, 0)), '  USA', ' USA')
                                                                                           ELSE SUBSTRING(pc.companyname, 0, CHARINDEX(' - ', pc.companyname, 0))
                                                                                       END AND lpc.dtDeleted IS NULL
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN lDivision d ON d.strDivision = SUBSTRING(pc.companyname, CHARINDEX(' - ', pc.companyname, 0)+3, LEN(pc.companyname) - (CHARINDEX(' - ', pc.companyname, 0)+3)+1) AND d.dtDeleted IS NULL
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN lMarketSegment ms ON ms.strMarketSegment = a.strsitecategory AND ms.dtDeleted IS NULL
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN lRegion r ON r.strRegion = CASE 
                                                                         WHEN a.region = 'New England' THEN
                                                                              'North East'
                                                                         WHEN a.region = 'Northeast' THEN
                                                                              'North East'
                                                                         ELSE a.region
                                                                     END AND r.dtDeleted IS NULL
                    WHERE a.appname != ''
                      AND a.appname IS NOT NULL  
                      AND a.[server] != ''
                      AND a.[server] IS NOT NULL
                      AND a.[server] != 'CTXT'
                      AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000),a.appurl) != ''
                      AND a.appurl IS NOT NULL 
                      AND tSiteMapping.intSiteID = s.intSiteID
                      AND isnull(tSiteMapping.intEntityID, 0) = isnull(e.intEntityID, 0)
                      AND isnull(tSiteMapping.intParentCompanyID, 0) = isnull(lpc.intParentCompanyID, 0)
                      AND isnull(tSiteMapping.intMarketSegmentID, 0) = isnull(ms.intMarketSegmentID, 0)
                      AND isnull(tSiteMapping.intRegionID, 0) = isnull(r.intRegionID, 0)
                      AND isnull(tSiteMapping.intdivisionid, 0) = isnull(d.intdivisionid, 0)
                      AND tSiteMapping.dtDeleted IS NULL)
```

Here are the rows in the table that have the conflict

> intSiteMappingID, intEntityID,    intParentCompanyID, intMarketSegmentID, intRegionID,    intSiteID,  dtEntered,  dtModified, dtDeleted,  intdivisionid
>
> 12816,    4,  NULL,   5,  NULL,   1394,   2011-12-17 00:17:24.283,    NULL,   NULL,   154
>
> 12512,    4,  NULL,   5,  NULL,   1394,   2011-12-16 09:32:41.100,    NULL,   2011-12-17 00:17:22.157,    154

The update should be updating the record with the NUll dtdeleted date and setting it to GETDATE() which appears to be throwing the error.

Comment: Please add table definition

Comment: table definition added

Comment: And what INSERT fails? I'm not about to guess which column is which...

Comment: Added Update statement that is failing as well as rows that are causing conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot really go through all this complex query but it appears that these 2 rows would be updated with same date from `GETDATE()` and since all other columns in the `UNIQUE` key are identical, this is in conflist with the `UNIQUE KEY` constraint.